# Are these two series really equal to each other? If so, why?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, functional-equations

The conjecture we are trying to prove is the following:

$$ x \in \mathbb{R^+} \implies -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)^n}{(2^n-1)n!} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 - x^{\frac{1}{2^n}}\right)$$

Note the left hand side is absolutely convergent while the right hand side is conditionally convergent. I have verified these for about 12 decimal digits to be equal. Moreover, they both obey the same functional equation $f(x^2) = f(x) -x + 1$.

The proof of the functional equation for the right hand side is trivial so we show the left hand side

$$  -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x^2)^n}{(2^n-1)n!}  = - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n\ln(x)^n}{(2^n-1)n!} = - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[\frac{\ln(x)^n}{(2^n-1)n!} + \frac{\ln(x)^n}{n!} \right] =  $$
$$-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)^n}{(2^n-1)n!} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{\ln(x)^n}{n!}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)^n}{(2^n-1)n!}-x+1$$

I have absolutely no reason to believe that just because these functions obey the same equation and are equal for at least 12 decimal digits (which is the limit of the calculator I'm using) that they are totally equal but this is a very odd coincidence to survive for so many digits.

Comment: Side note: How is this related to complex analysis since we have $x\in\mathbb R$? I am genuinely asking as I am curious.

Comment: The two series originated by a failed attempt to extend $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{2^n}$ outside of the unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Using Mathematica I found that the equality is correct upto $x=10^9$.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure both sums converge in the desired domains?

Comment: @K.defaoite I am 100% sure the Left hand side sum converges in the desired domain, I'm intuitively certain the right hand side converges on the desired domain but i don't have overwhelming evidence of this

Comment: Extend $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} z^{2^n}$ outside of the unit disc in what sense? The unit circle is the natural boundary of that function, so it has no analytic continuation across any part of the unit circle.

Comment: i was exploring ways to extend it in a "natural" but non-analytic way, i.e. trying to generalize analytic continuation. Unfortunately this rather specific strategy i had developed failed because it yielded a series that by some bad luck was entirely equal to an older series i had seen that failed to yield me the desired trans-analytic continuation.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

They are in fact equal.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)^n}{(2^n-1)n!} =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{2} \right)^n}{n!} \cdot \frac{1}{1-2^{-n}}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{2} \right)^n}{n!} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^\infty(2^{-n})^{k-1}
$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{2^{k}} \right)^n}{n!} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (e^{\frac{\ln(x)}{2^{k}}}-1)= \sum_{k=1}^\infty (x^{\frac{1}{2^k}}-1).$$

Comment: I do not follow this when $x>1$.

Comment: @GEdgar I don't think anything changes if $x>0.$ To justify reversing the order of summation note that  $\sum_{k,n} \left|\frac{\ln(x)^n}{2^{kn}n!}\right|\le \sum_{k,n}\frac{1}{2^k}\cdot \frac{|(\ln x)|^n}{n!} = e^{|\ln(x)|} -1 < \infty.$